# make two floating divs the same height dynamically

Tags: html, css, css-float

Situation: I have a container with two direct children, *we will call them **left** and **right***.
**left** should never be allowed to extend past the *height* of **right**, however **right** should be allowed to extend past the *height* of **left**.

[image]

I can't figure out how to do this with CSS (hopefully while maintaining the simplicity of my markup)

example html

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left">
        left
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        right
    </div>
</div>
```

example css

```
.wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px 0;
}
.left {
    float: left;
    width: 60px;
    background-color: #999;   
}
.right {
    float: left;
    width: 540px;
    border: 4px solid #666;
    padding: 8px;
}
```

[or see what I mean here](http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/Zhkk9/3/)

Comment: i'm assuming this is probably simple... i'm just searching for the wrong thing maybe??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to rely on JavaScript for this kind of problem, you could just always set the min-height of the left column according to the height of the right column, or something similar to that!

Using jQuery, this might help you getting started! http://www.cssnewbie.com/equal-height-columns-with-jquery/

Comment: give you the check for the static *min-*height (i'll assume you meant to say min instead of max)

Answer (score 3):

It's kind of an common problem. The thing is, you need either a CSS/background image trick or use javascript. One common used is [Faux Columns](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/).

Comment: +1 for faux columns. It is a common robust pattern that adheres to the principle of progressive enhacement.

Comment: They also look nice in your home!